# Revealing missing tags on a website using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am working on a project in which I am attempting to extract all the urls from the frontpage of the CNN/Politics webpage. I've scanned through the html source-code, and have found the article links to be located in a 'li' tag.

I am getting all the content under said tag by doing the following:

```
url = 'https://edition.cnn.com/politics'

r1 = requests.get(url)
coverpage = r1.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(coverpage, 'lxml')

links = soup.find_all('li')
```

This provides me with a list of objects that are similar to this;
"Sitemap"

I am not specifying a class since the class changes from url to url.

I am however not getting all 'li' objects when running this code. When inspecting the webpage source there are many more 'li' objects that are of class name "cd *blabla*", but beautifulsoup does not seem to recognise these. I don't know if they are somehow embedded in another tag or why they are not extracted.

I wish to extract links to the articles that one can navigate to from the politics coverpage.
How can I go about solving this? Is there an easier way to find the links to other articles on the page.

Comment: Are you sure all `<li>` elements are available via a plain requests or may ome be loaded via js?

Comment: I don't know, they may be. I'm quite new to working with the library. Is there a way to access the tags if they are loaded via js? - or to check whether that is the case first and foremost.

Comment: check my answer I guess I made it clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good website. When you go in depth on how the website loads the data and when you see the source code of the website, all the data is held inside the script tag in a `Javascript Object` form. It's not a `JSON`. If you pull the data inside the script then you will get all the article links, images etc...

Because it's a Javascript Object, you need 3rd party libraries to convert to a json. I used `demjson` library to do this job - https://github.com/dmeranda/demjson

The below script saves the data to a json file. Once you have the json getting all the links shouldn't be difficult.

```
import requests, demjson, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("https://edition.cnn.com/politics")

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

script = None
for i in soup.find_all("script"):
    if "window.CNN" in i.text:
        script = i.get_text(strip=True)

if script is None: print("No data found")
else:
    data = script.partition("CNN.contentModel")[-1].partition("FAVE.settings")[0]
    json_data = demjson.decode(data[data.index('{'):-1])

    with open("data.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(json_data, f)
```

Output:

```
{
    "hasVideo": false,
    "layout": "no-rail",
    "vertical": "politics",
    "sectionName": "politics",
    "pageType": "section",
    "env": "prod",
    "type": "page",
    "analytics": {
        "pageTop": {},
        "headline": "",
        "author": "",
        "showName": "",
        "subSectionName": "",
        "isArticleVideoCollection": false,
        "publishDate": "2014-02-27T01:35:32Z",
        "lastUpdatedDate": "2020-08-06T09:31:15Z",
        "pageBranding": "10-minute-preview",
        "cep_topics": {
            "brsf": [],
            "buzz": [],
            "iabt": [],
            "sent": [
                "16B6"
            ],
            "tags": [],
            "shortSource": "se_politics",
            "source": "section_politics"
        },
        "chartbeat": {
            "sections": ""
        },
        "branding_content_page": "10-minute-preview",
        "branding_content_zone": [
            "default"
        ],
        "branding_content_container": [
            "default"
        ],
        "branding_content_card": [
            ""
        ]
    },
    "edition": "international",
    "sourceId": "section_politics",
    "title": "CNNPolitics - Political News, Analysis and Opinion",
    "siblings": {
        "articleList": [
            {
                "uri": "/2020/08/06/politics/donald-trump-mail-in-voting-election/index.html",
                "headline": "Trump's mail-in voting falsehoods are part of a wide campaign to discredit the election",
                "thumbnail": "//cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200805203446-02-donald-trump-0805-small-11.jpg",
                "duration": "",
                "description": "<a href=\"http://www.cnn.com/specials/politics/president-donald-trump-45\" target=\"_blank\">President Donald Trump's</a> barrage of <a href=\"http://www.cnn.com/2020/08/05/politics/fact-check-trump-fox-friends-pandemic-biden-protests/index.html\" target=\"_blank\">challenges to the reputation, structures and traditions</a> of elections is conjuring up a contentious and potentially constitutionally critical three-month period for America's democracy.",
                "layout": ""
            },
            {
                "uri": "/2020/08/05/politics/donald-trump-press-briefing-beirut-coronavirus-voting-fact-check/index.html",
                "headline": "Fact check: At briefing, Trump continues to mislead on coronavirus, mail-in voting and Beirut",
                "thumbnail": "//cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200805203446-02-donald-trump-0805-small-11.jpg",
                "duration": "",
                "description": "President Donald Trump ended his Wednesday much like he began it, by repeating falsehood after falsehood.",
                "layout": ""
            },
            {
                "uri": "/2020/08/05/politics/state-department-russian-disinformation-report/index.html",
                "headline": "US accuses Russia of conducting sophisticated disinformation and propaganda campaign  ",
                "thumbnail": "//cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170626163907-russia-dnc-hacking-ron-2-00000808-small-11.jpg",
                "duration": "",
                "description": "A <a href=\"https://content.govdelivery.com/attachments/USSTATEBPA/2020/08/05/file_attachments/1512230/Pillars%20of%20Russias%20Disinformation%20and%20Propaganda%20Ecosystem_08-04-20%20%281%29.pdf\" target=\"_blank\">new report</a> from the US State Department accuses Russia of conducting a sophisticated disinformation and propaganda campaign that uses a variety of approaches including Kremlin-aligned news sites to promote their agenda.",
                "layout": ""
            },
            {
                "uri": "/2020/08/05/politics/fact-check-trump-ad-biden-basement-delaware-photos-iowa/index.html",
                "headline": "<strong>Fact check: </strong>Trump ad edits out microphone and trees from Biden photo to make him seem alone in basement",
                "thumbnail": "//cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200803235935-01-joe-biden-campaign-0720-small-11.jpg",
                "duration": "",
                "description": "A new <a href=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9PUfxZQa7WQ&feature=emb_title\" target=\"_blank\">ad</a> from President Donald Trump's campaign deceptively alters a photo of former Vice President Joe Biden campaigning outdoors in Iowa to make it seem as if Biden is \"hiding\" in his Delaware basement.",
                "layout": ""
            },
            {
                "uri": "/2020/08/05/politics/mark-meadows-unemployment-benefits-extension-coronavirus-relief-cnntv/index.html",
                "headline": "White House chief of staff floats executive action on unemployment and evictions if Congress can't strike deal",
                "thumbnail": "//cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/191219132522-03-mark-meadows-lead-image-small-11.jpg",
                "duration": "",
                "description": "White House chief of staff Mark Meadows said Wednesday that <a href=\"https://www.cnn.com/specials/politics/president-donald-trump-45\" target=\"_blank\">President Donald Trump</a> is prepared to take executive action on eviction protection and extending enhanced unemployment benefits if Congress isn't close to <a href=\"https://www.cnn.com/2020/08/05/politics/congress-stimulus-negotiations/index.html\" target=\"_blank\">a coronavirus recovery package</a> by Friday. ",
                "layout": ""
            },
            {
                "uri": "/2020/08/05/politics/trump-campaign-four-debates/index.html",
                "headline": "Trump campaign calls for a fourth presidential debate, citing early voting",
                "thumbnail": "//cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200709094609-trump-biden-split-small-1-1.jpg",
                "duration": "",
                "description": "<a href=\"https://www.cnn.com/election/2020/candidate/trump\" target=\"_blank\">Donald Trump's</a> presidential campaign called for an additional presidential debate in a letter to the Commission on Presidential Debates on Wednesday. ",
                "layout": ""
            },
            {
                "uri": "/2020/08/05/politics/schlapp-mail-voting-expansion-nevada-fact-check/index.html",
                "headline": "<strong>Fact Check: </strong>With vote by mail expansion, can Nevada voters cast ballots after Election Day?",
                "thumbnail": "//cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200610082429-voting-north-las-vegas-small-11.jpg",
                "duration": "",
                "description": "President Donald Trump reversed his stance on voting by mail Tuesday when he <a href=\"https://www.cnn.com/2020/08/04/politics/donald-trump-mail-in-voting-florida/index.html\" target=\"_blank\">tweeted</a> that doing so in Florida is \"safe and secure.\" When asked about the reversal later Tuesday afternoon, Trump seemed to imply that Republican-run states with existing mail-in voting programs were up to par, but Democratic states establishing or expanding mail-in voting during the pandemic were not.",
                "layout": ""
            },

...
...
...
```

Comment: Really really nice, thank you so much! This so far seems the simplest way to go about extracting all the data I need!

Answer (score 2):

To deal with pages that contains js to load element. Try to use selenium and most of the time it may work.
You have to go through the documentation https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html such as the installation and the driver.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

url = "https://edition.cnn.com/politics"
driver.get(url)
req = driver.page_source
driver.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(req, "html.parser")

result = soup.find_all(class_="cd__headline-text")


for i in result:
    print(i.text)
```

Output:

```
Trump's mail-in voting falsehoods are part of a wide campaign to discredit the election
Fact check: At briefing, Trump continues to mislead on coronavirus, mail-in voting and Beirut
US accuses Russia of conducting sophisticated disinformation and propaganda campaign  
Fact check: Trump ad edits out microphone and trees from Biden photo to make him seem alone in basement
White House chief of staff floats executive action on unemployment and evictions if Congress can't strike deal
Trump campaign calls for a fourth presidential debate, citing early voting
Fact Check: With vote by mail expansion, can Nevada voters cast ballots after Election Day?
Trump bests Biden in July fundraising but money gap between the campaigns has essentially closed
New York Times: Prosecutors subpoenaed Trump's bank in criminal inquiry 
Analysis: But, seriously -- what is this country going to do with its kids this fall?
Analysis: This week's 'smooth' primaries almost felt normal. Here's why.
Brianna Keilar debunks Trump campaign official: You've got to shovel B.S.
Illinois Republican congressman tests positive for coronavirus
Former Army Delta Force officer, US ambassador sign secretive contract to develop Syrian oil fields
Supreme Court lifts lower court order that would have required more Covid-related safety measures in California jail
Ex-acting AG Sally Yates defends FBI investigation into Flynn, calls Barr move to drop charges 'highly irregular'
Esper says 'most believe' Beirut explosion 'was an accident' after Trump claimed it was an attack
Fact check: Trump makes at least 20 false claims in Fox & Friends interview
Trump trashes Obama's Lewis eulogy that pressed for voting rights
Trump still not grasping the severity of the pandemic, source tells CNN 
Republican senators grow anxious over direction of stimulus talks with no deal in sight
Joe Biden will no longer travel to Milwaukee to accept Democratic nomination
Analysis: Trump's interview debacle sends a warning for the fall campaign  
Fauci says US has suffered from pandemic 'as much or worse than anyone' 
Primary results: Key takeaways from Kansas
CNN holds elected officials and candidates accountable. View our Facts First database
Seven governors join deal in pursuit of first multistate coordinated testing strategy
Hogan overrules Maryland county order delaying in-person education at private schools, including Barron Trump's 
Birx defends herself as Pelosi accuses Trump administration of spreading disinformation on Covid-19
See latest Trump and Biden head-to-head polling
Top Senate Republican pushes back against Trump's unsubstantiated claims mail-in-voting leads to mass fraud
Republican operatives are helping Kanye West get on general election ballots
Progressive who unseated longtime Democratic congressman says 'people are looking for a fighter right now'
Trump said he may deliver convention speech from White House
Biden clarifies he has not taken cognitive test
Fact check: Biden says he hasn't taken a cognitive test. Is he flip-flopping?
WNBA players wear shirts supporting Sen. Kelly Loeffler's challenger -- including some from team she co-owns
Trump campaign sues Nevada over plan to mail ballots to all registered voters
Analysis: Trump may finally realize he's suppressing his own vote
Trump continues to lose ground in 2020 election as nation grapples with coronavirus
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try to see if I can get the url's associated with each headline in this manner! I'd like to go through each url and extract the text from the article. Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. Just try to learn selenium as it can help scraping websites that contains js.

Answer (score 1):

You code works properly I tried it but check whether if you're not missing any requirement
like `lxml` installed here is what I did

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://edition.cnn.com/politics'

r1 = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r1.content, 'lxml')
li = soup.find_all('li')
print(li)
```

and notice that `find_all` method returns i array so if you want one by one you can simply loop on it and print every sing `li` like the following

```
for i in li:
    print(i.prettify())
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for testing it out. It works fine for me too. The problem is that it runs, but there are some *li* tags missing as specified in the original post. They might be embedded or as Cobalt mentioned previously that they could be called via js. I don't know how to access these 'hidden' tags - which is where the article links seem to be located.